# Vue3 child component not updating

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a vue3 + composition api + typescript setup.

My problem is, when I load this page, the title in child component doesn't update the value.

I checked Vue DevTools, the prop value did change, but it is not updating the ui.
I also tried displaying the title at Home.vue, it work as expected.

Below is a simplified version of my code

Home.vue

```
<template>
      <SummaryCard
        :title="homeStore.title"
      />
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { useHomeStore } from '@/views/main/home/stores/homeStore.ts'
import { SummaryCard} from './SummaryCard.vue'

const homeStore = useHomeStore()
</script>
```

SummaryCard.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ title }}
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { defineProps } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps({
  title: String,
})

const { title } = props
</script>
```

homeStore.ts

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import { ref, toRefs, onMounted } from 'vue'

export const useHomeStore = defineStore('HomeStore', () => {
  const initialState = () => ({
    title: 'NO TITLE',
  })

  const state = ref(initialState())
  const { title } = toRefs(state.value)

  onMounted(async () => (title.value = await getTitleApi())

  const reset = () => Object.assign(state.value, initialState())

  return {
    title,
    reset,
  }
})
```

p.s. i tried adding a key to the child component, it work, but is there any alternative way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do such thing:

```
const { title } = props;
```

This way you ask props (a reactive) to get its prop `title` as a string, not a ref.

All components props are accessible in the template without declaring them in `<script setup>`.
So just remove this line and it will work.

If you want to have a title ref in the script, use `toRef()`: https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-utilities#toref 
But for me that's ugly. Use props as it is: `props.title`. That way you will know that you are referring to a component prop, not some ref declared in the script.